# Python check if item is in dictionary items

Tags: python, dictionary, items

Is it possible to check in python if an item is in a dictionary of items in a way like below:

```
for x in rows:
    print(x.items())
    for item in seq.items():
        print(item)
        if item in x.items():
            print("got it")
```

```
Rows = [{'name': 'Alice', 'AGATC': '2', 'AATG': '8', 'TATC': '3'},
        {'name': 'Bob', 'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5'},
        {'name': 'Charlie', 'AGATC': '3', 'AATG': '2', 'TATC': '5'}]

Seq = {'AGATC': 4, 'AATG': 1, 'TATC': 5}
```

I know that I can check if value exist but I want check if whole item exists. It will be an easier way to do this.

Comment: You could decompose an item into its key value pair - i.e `key, value = item`. Then use the following to check if the item is in the dict `if (key in x and x[key]==value): print("got it")`. That way you don't have to needlessly iterate over every item in the dict

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to loop through the rows and then loop through the items that you're looking for and check if any of those items are in a row... yes, that is very possible:

```
rows = [{'name': 'Alice', 'AGATC': '2', 'AATG': '8', 'TATC': '3'},
        {'name': 'Bob', 'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5'},
        {'name': 'Charlie', 'AGATC': '3', 'AATG': '2', 'TATC': '5'}]

seq = {'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5'}

for row in rows:
    if any(row.get(key) == value for key, value in seq.items()):
        print("Got it")
```

This way you're picking a row and checking if any of the items from `seq` can be found in the row. The finding itself checks whether the whole item exists, just like you want, by calling [`row.get(key)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) first (and checking if they key exists in the first place) and then by comparing it to the value you want it to be equal.

---

We're lucky that `.get(key[, default])`

> *Return[s] the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.*

as such you don't need to worry about crashing when comparing values of non-existent keys.

Instead of `any()`, you could also keep your 2nd loop and know exactly which item was found if you care about that information.

Comment: Thank You very much. I tried something similar but i made some mistake but now it;s works.

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark the answer as accepted if that solves it or ask for more help if you run into problems with my code.